# Typescript: how to use a method decorator in an instance member property (mixin)?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, decorator, nestjs, mixins

**Background**

We have implemented a mixin like this (simplified):

```js
export type Constructor<I> = new (...args: any[]) => I;

export interface IBaseService<T = any> {
  create: (data: any) => Promise<T>;
}

export function BaseService<T>(entity: Constructor<T>): Type<IBaseService<T>> {
  class BaseServiceHost implements IBaseService<T> {
    public repository: Repository<T>;

    create(data: DeepPartial<T>): Promise<T> {
      const newResource = this.repository.create(data);
      return this.repository.save(newResource);
    }

  }
  return BaseServiceHost;
}
```

Now my service extends `BaseService` like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ResponseService extends BaseService(ResponseEntity) {
  private readonly respondentService: RespondentService;
  private readonly surveyService: SurveyService;

  create = async (data: ResponseInput): Promise<ResponseEntity> => {
    const respondent = await this.respondentService.findByNaturalKey(data.respondentKey);
    const survey = await this.surveyService.findById(data.surveyId);
    return super.create({ respondent, survey, ...data })
  };
```

... and this works fine.

PS.: `create` has to be a property now, otherwise I'd get the following error:

```
Class 'IBaseTenantService<ResponseEntity>' defines instance member property 'create',
but extended class 'ResponseService' defines it as instance member function.
```

**Problem**

The `create` method (now a property), needs the method decorator `Transactional()`,
but the construction

```js
  @Transactional()  // <--- error here
  create = async (data: ResponseInput): Promise<ResponseEntity> => {
    const respondent = await this.respondentService.findByNaturalKey(data.respondentKey);
    const survey = await this.surveyService.findById(data.surveyId);
    return super.create({ respondent, survey, ...data })
  };
```

gives the following error:

```
The return type of a property decorator function must be either 'void' or 'any'.
  Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
```

**Question**

How to use the `Transactional()` in the `create` property? Workarounds?

Comment: `@Transactional` came from `typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked` or what?

Comment: @Micael_Levi, yes it does. That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

this might sound dumb but ever you tried this:

```
  @Transactional()
  async create(data: ResponseInput): Promise<ResponseEntity> {
    const respondent = await this.respondentService.findByNaturalKey(data.respondentKey);
    const survey = await this.surveyService.findById(data.surveyId);
    return super.create({ respondent, survey, ...data })
  };
```

?

Comment: @Micael_Levi, the reason I cannot use this construction is because it raises the error ```Class 'IBaseTenantService<ResponseEntity>' defines instance member property 'create',
but extended class 'ResponseService' defines it as instance member function.```